# tab completion favors "builtin" (command) over "build" (directory)

Tags: bash, readline

If I type "`bui`" + [Tab] bash auto-completes to `builtin` although there exists a `build` directory, so this should be an ambiguity and I expect bash to only complete until `buil`.

What's wrong here? (Using Ubuntu 16.04/17.04)

Comment: Surprisingly, if you create a folder *cat* and place an executable file in it, then type `ca<tab><tab>` it shows you `cat/file` but not the `cat` command any more. I mean the opposite as you reported. (Likely because `builtin` is a builtin and `cat` a program. Looks like there is a priority: 1. builtins, 2. files and folders, 3. executables in $PATH)